# Add a Module Form to a front page region

Tags: 7, blocks

As the title reads, I'm attempting to add a custom made module (simple contact form) into a region on my front page (this may be used other places as well, but for not just the front page). Could some one lend me their eyes/advice on how to do this correctly. The region on my page is labeled sidebar_first. I have attempted to add it via a hook_block_view() functionallity, however nothing seems to be taking.

.module

```
function honey_front_page_form_menu(){
global $user;
//Main Page Call Back
$items['front_page_form'] = array(
    'page callback' =>'_honey_front_page_init',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'title' => t('Honey Contact page Form'),
);

}

function honey_front_page_form_admin_form(){

  $form['front_form'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Admin Menu'),
);

  $form['front_form']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('name')),
    '#required' => TRUE,

  );

  $form['front_form']['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('email')),
    '#required' => TRUE,

  );

  $form['front_form']['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('phone')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 15

  );
    $form['front_form']['comments'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('comments')),
    '#required' => FALSE,

  );

  $form['front_form']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'SUBMIT NOW',
    '#field_prefix' => '<h3>',
    '#field_suffix'=> '</h3>'

  );

}

function honey_front_page_form_block_view($delta = ''){
//ensures form is only called on the front page.

// if (!drupal_is_front_page()){
//     return NULL;
// }


    if($delta == '1'){
        $form = drupal_render( drupal_get_form('honey_front_page_form_admin_form'));
    $block = array(
        // 'subject' => t('Subject'),
        'content' => $form,
    );

    return $block;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Drupal block APIs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7). You need to use [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) to define a block. Then use [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to return the rendered content of the block. You will still need to include the block, ether programmatically, or by using admin/structure/block.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the advice and direction. I didn't think I was needing to define the module in that manner. I was simply thinking I'd be able to piggy back the forms into a block.